# Reading and using a string of characters through user input? C# (Arduino Uno)

Tags: c#, input, arduino

I'm sure the answer is very simple, but I haven't found it anyway.
Actually, this bit of code almost does what I want it to do... It waits for input, then once the user has entered something, it checks whether or not the first letter begins with a vowel.

For yes and no different messages are displayed. It will do this fine... but if I add `Serial.println(input)` to check what was actually read, I get the first letter only. It seems as though it's only actually saving the first character into the first memory slot, and nothing else.

I want to keep the whole word, be able to print it out and use it later. `Serial.println(input[0])` prints the same thing as the previously mentioned statement, and `Serial.println(input[1])` (or anything where 1 is higher) does not print anything, so I'm assuming that the issue is in reading the characters in the first place.

```
Serial.println("Enter a word: ");
while (!Serial.available()) {
    ;
}
char input[100] = {Serial.read()};
if (input[0] == 'a' || input[0] == 'e' || input[0] == 'i' || input[0] == 'o' || input[0] == 'u'){
    Serial.println("the word begins with a vowel\n");
}
else{
    Serial.println("the word does not begin with a vowel");
}
```

Comment: If this busy waiting  `while (!Serial.available()) {
    ;
}` is the correct way for your library  then don't use it. Search for another one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to [Arduino::Serial.Read()](http://arduino.cc/en/Serial/Read) documentation:

> Returns
>
> the first byte of incoming serial data available (or -1 if no data is
>   available) - int

So it appears to me, you simply use the wrong function here.

You probably need to use [Arduino::Serial.ReadBytes()](http://arduino.cc/en/Serial/ReadBytes)